# FireFox 24 Unresponsive Script erorr

Tags: jquery, firefox, firebug

First, I can't give exact code due to privacy issues, But i will try to make it exact as possible.

```
$(".page").each( function() {
 var this_dom = $(this);
 var this_class = this_dom.attr("class");
 var page_no = this_class.substr(this_class.indexOf("page_")+5,1);
 var obj = {};
 obj.id = 'page_' + page_no;
 obj.encoded_html = encodeBase64("<html><head><style>"+css+"</style></head><body>"+ $(this).html() +"</body></html>" ); 
 obj.quality = 10;
 obj.height = 2200;
 obj.width = 1700;

 obj.format = 'png';                    
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: "some url",
    data: obj,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
            page_cnt++;
        $("form.cmxform").append('<input type="hidden" name="page_'+(page_no)+'" value="'+res['img']+'">'); // PRODUCTION

        if (page_cnt === page_total) {
            form.submit(); 
        }
        return false;
    }
  }); 
});
```

So what this does, is it loops through all the tags that have a .page class, encodes what's inside, post's it with the ajax where it is rendered into a png then recoded sent back and then appended to the form. Once it has gone through all of them it then submits the data uri's to a database via another .php file.

This has worked for so long, and with other forms i have it still works fine, but one that i do have has 7 "pages" and after about the 4th one i get the Unresponsive script error message in FF, and this just recently started to happen. Works fine in Chrome, even IE. Also, if FireBug is open, this never fails, I don't even put in break points or anything, just having it open everything seems to work fine.

Also, the Unresponsive Script error is random, one time it might the jquery library, another time it will be the base64 library i use, but mostly it spits out the jquery library as having the error.

I am fairly new to jquery and js, pretty much self taught, and SO has helped so much, can you help me again?!

Comment: Possibly an ajax timeout? Any indication?

Comment: I have this set globally: 

$.ajaxSetup({
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  timeout: 20000
 });

It use to be 10000 but i doubled it to see if that would help, it didn't.

Comment: Probably not your requests then. See my answer on how to call this function with it's own timeout instead of firefox intervening.

Answer (score 0):

Could be something to do with the server request taking too long, firefox extension, or something else. Probably need to use something like this to bypass firefox timeouts.

```
setTimeout(pageFunction, 8000);

function pageFunction () {
    $(".page").each( function() {
        var this_dom = $(this);
        var this_class = this_dom.attr("class");
        var page_no = this_class.substr(this_class.indexOf("page_")+5,1);
        var obj = {};
        obj.id = 'page_' + page_no;
        obj.encoded_html = encodeBase64("<html><head><style>"+css+"</style></head><body>"+ $(this).html() +"</body></html>" ); 
        obj.quality = 10;
        obj.height = 2200;
        obj.width = 1700;
        obj.format = 'png';                    
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some url",
            data: obj,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res) {
                page_cnt++;
                $("form.cmxform").append('<input type="hidden" name="page_'+(page_no)+'" value="'+res['img']+'">'); // PRODUCTION
                if (page_cnt === page_total) {
                    form.submit(); 
                } return false;
            }
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: So I tried this out, first with the 8000 and it failed, then I increased it to 20000 and it fails after about 12 seconds. To be honest, I am not even sure if its failing here, but before I can move forward, I need to make sure it's not here.

Comment: I should also mention that I did try it the above way before, but I re-tried just to make sure. Another thing I tried was to "bundle" up each of the "pages" into an array and then post the array where it was handled and then sent back to me and appended to the <form> tag and then submitted. The results were the same.

Comment: No exceptions in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 24 slightly changed how it detects scripts that are blocking the page so the user can't interact with it.

In particular, it now includes all time spent in sync XMLHttpRequest calls as time the script is running.  Since you're globally forcing all jQuery `ajax()` stuff to be synchronous, the time those network accesses take is now counted as part of your script execution time, since during that time the user can't interact with the page.  After a script has been blocking for 10 seconds (by default; there's a preference to change the exact time) Firefox will ask the user whether to kill off the offending script; that's the prompt you're seeing.